# Is there an Angular2 view updated lifecycle hook?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have a child component, receiving data from its parent and displaying text in a div. It is possible the parent sends `undefined` as data. When it does the div is supposed to transition its height to 0, which I do via css transition. As I don't know the length of the text, the div's height is supposed to be transitioned to `auto`. I found a code sample doing so, which I've transformed to fit into my component.

```
export class LanguageDetail implements OnChange, OnInit {
    @Input() language: Language
    @ViewChild("detailPanel") detailPanel: ElementRef;

    private shownLanguage: Language;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.shownLanguage = new Language();
    }

    ngOnChange() {
        if (this.detailPanel) {
            var detailPanel: JQuery = $(this.detailPanel.nativeElement);

            if (this.language) {
                ...
                // calculate the end height and apply a transition with fixed values to this.shownLanguage
                this.shownLanguage = this.language;

                oldHeight = detailPanel.height();
                detailPanel.height("auto");
                newHeight = detailPanel.height();
                detailPanel.height(oldHeight);
                ...
            } else {
                ...
                // do a transition to 0 for this.shownLanguage
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, when ngOnChange gets called, the property language has actually changed, the view however is bound to `this.shownLanguage` and does not actually update when `this.language` is assigned to it within the ngOnChange function. Same goes for a binding to `this.language` itself. The OnChange event gets hit too early.
With the text missing in the div, I do not receive the correct height of it and so my calculation runs incorrect. Is there actually an event that is triggered when the view changes or is there a way to force redrawing of the view so I can actually get the div with the correct height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, what about `AfterViewChecked`

```
  [LifecycleHooks.OnInit, OnInit],
  [LifecycleHooks.OnDestroy, OnDestroy],
  [LifecycleHooks.DoCheck, DoCheck],
  [LifecycleHooks.OnChanges, OnChanges],
  [LifecycleHooks.AfterContentInit, AfterContentInit],
  [LifecycleHooks.AfterContentChecked, AfterContentChecked],
  [LifecycleHooks.AfterViewInit, AfterViewInit],
  [LifecycleHooks.AfterViewChecked, AfterViewChecked],
```

`AfterViewChecked` - Implement this interface to get notified after every check of your component's view.

Comment: I tried AfterViewChecked and it gets called multiple times when my value changes. It appears to me that it gets called for every component, not only for the partial view of the LanguageDetail component, which actually implements AfterViewChecked.

Comment: Funny, now it works and AfterViewChecked gets called only twice, as it should. Well, thanks.